# Bootstrap datetimepicker disable past dates & current date?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to disable past dates & current date, but I'm unable to disable current date. **Below my code, only disables past dates**, please correct my code if I'm wrong, thanks in advance.

```
 <script>
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
       minDate: moment(1, 'h')
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try disabledDates with minDate:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  
 minDate:new Date(),
 disabledDates: [new Date()]
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/645/)

Comment: How to enable from last two days?

Comment: change the minDate parameter and remove the disabledDates parameter. 

https://jsfiddle.net/65vaoqkw/647/

Answer (score 3):

use the minDate and disabledDates:

```
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({  
      minDate:new Date(),
      disabledDates: [new Date()]
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '**minDate**' option of **datetimepicker** for staring date, and use '**disabledDates**' option of **datetimepicker** to disable the previous date and by using both of the option together you'll get only future dates from current date, user will not able select to the previous date from current date.(This type of combination will be help when you are trying to use **datetimepicker** on any **booking system**.)

```
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    clearButton: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    time: false,
    minDate:new Date(),
    disabledDates: [new Date()]
 });
```