# datetimepicker - disabling some days in the calendar

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(".dtp").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-M-D hh:mm',
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

I am using `datetimepicker` from Bootstrap and I'm trying to disable some days, based on information in my database.

For example all Mondays and Saturdays could be disabled. I can't seem to  find information about how to do this.

Comment: try to google [bootstrap datetimepicker disable days](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=off&ei=GsevWojZLImkUZKkicAC&q=bootstrap+datetimepicker+disable+days&oq=bootstrap+datetimepicker+disable+days&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1j0i22i30k1l6.2460.2460.0.3258.1.1.0.0.0.0.87.87.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.87....0.x0LdxhSicb8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datetimepicker disable past dates & current date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610281/bootstrap-datetimepicker-disable-past-dates-current-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of datepicker has this option.

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled

See Answer in this similar question

[Limit bootstrap-datepicker to weekdays only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234153/limit-bootstrap-datepicker-to-weekdays-only)

Comment: Please include the relevant parts from the links you provide

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates), you can use `disabledDates` :

```
$(".dtp").datetimepicker({
    format: 'Y-M-D hh:mm', 
    minDate: new Date(),
    disabledDates: [
         moment("12/25/2013"),
         new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
         "11/22/2013 00:53"
    ]
 });
```